# TypeScript global modules declaration

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm developing a NodeJS API using TypeScript. I have several .ts file and in all of them I'm importing external modules again and again (e.g. soap, xmlParser, url, underscore, etc.).

Is there any convenient way to declare them somehow globally and use them without import them in each .ts file?

Thanks,

Comment: Importing them in each module is idiomatic and is considered normal. It'll generally be easier to maintain later when each module lists out its dependencies rather than depending on external side-effects. – Though, you could assign them as properties of [`global`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/globals.html#globals_global).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any convenient way to declare them somehow globally and use them without import them in each .ts file?

Have a file `utils.ts` and just export these from them. Now you only need to import `utils`.